# Error when deploying Meteor app to Galaxy

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm new to Meteor so forgive me if this is too simple, I continuously receive the following errors when trying to deploy my app.

I've desperately scoured the internet in hopes of finding the answer but the same error is still coming up.

```
> 95gp
> 2016-09-06 06:44:07-05:00Application process starting, version: 1 on apprunner (embedded)
> 95gp
> 2016-09-06 06:44:09-05:00/app/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:333
> 95gp
> 2016-09-06 06:44:09-05:00}).run();
> 95gp
> 2016-09-06 06:44:09-05:00 ^
> 95gp
> 2016-09-06 06:44:09-05:00
> 95gp
> 2016-09-06 06:44:09-05:00Error: $ROOTURL, if specified, must be an URL_
> 95gp
> 2016-09-06 06:44:09-05:00 at Error (native)
> 95gp
> 2016-09-06 06:44:09-05:00 at packages/meteor/urlserver.js:8:1_
> 95gp
> 2016-09-06 06:44:09-05:00 at packages/meteor/urlserver.js:19:1_
> 95gp
> 2016-09-06 06:44:09-05:00 at /app/bundle/programs/server/packages/meteor.js:1365:3
> 95gp
> 2016-09-06 06:44:09-05:00 at /app/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:292:10
> 95gp
> 2016-09-06 06:44:09-05:00 at Array.forEach (native)
> 95gp
> 2016-09-06 06:44:09-05:00 at Function..each..forEach (/app/bundle/programs/server/nodemodules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)_
> 95gp
> 2016-09-06 06:44:09-05:00 at /app/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:128:5
> 95gp
> 2016-09-06 06:44:09-05:00Application exited with code: 1 signal: null
> 95gp
> 2016-09-06 06:44:09-05:00Application process closed with code: 1 signal: null
> 95gp
> 2016-09-06 06:44:19-05:00The container has crashed. A new container will be started to replace it.
```

All help is appreciated,

Cheers

Comment: can you also share the command you write to deploy and the settings file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok according to the logs you've shared $ROOTURL is not defined. Create a settings.json file in the root of your meteor project.

Should contain a structure such as:

```
{
    "galaxy.meteor.com": {
    "env": {
        "ROOT_URL": "http://yourappname.meteorapp.com/",
        "DEPLOY_HOSTNAME":"galaxy.meteor.com",
        "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://mongourl"
     }
  }
}
```

Then you can take a look at the deployment instructions that are on the galaxy website.

http://galaxy-guide.meteor.com/deploy-guide.html